# Screen width and height LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am making a simple LWJGL program and would like to be able to use the width and height of the window. I can do it now I just have to use `Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth()` but I have seen people use just `Display.getWidth()`

So my question is why is this happening, and what do I need to change for it to just use `Display.getWidth();`

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of LWJGL [according to the documentation](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getWidth%28%29) says that it has a static method called getWidth. Make sure you're invoking it by it's class name and not on an object - as it's static.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am using JRE1.6 and LWJGL version 2.9 as far I know they are OK together.

Comment: And I am calling it as a class, not an object, this is what it is `glOrtho(0, Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), 0, Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight(), -1, 1);`

Answer (score -1):

In LWJGL, there are two display classes, one in:

- org.lwjgl.opengl

and the other in:

- org.lwjgl.util

If you import from the opengl package, you don't need getDisplayMode() and if you import from the util package you do.